# How to use custom DNS server for selected domains only?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

There are quite few nice DNS service providers that do region unblocking and advertisement blocking. But I'm not too fond of sharing all my DNS queries with them.

How I can use their DNS services only for manually selected domains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/custom-dns` with

```
server=/example.com/xx.xx.xx.xx
server=/example.net/xx.xx.xx.xx
```

where `xx.xx.xx.xx` is a ip address of a DNS server and restart Network Manager

```
service network-manager restart
```